# openbim-components with node js

Tags: node.js, three.js, nestjs, ifc, bim

How can I use the openbim-components library in Nest.js or at least in Node.js?

All I need is to convert a file in ifc format to JSON and frag for optimization on the frontend. An example can be found on this website, but it's for frontend, whereas I want to do it on my microservice: [example](https://docs.thatopen.com/Tutorials/FragmentIfcLoader#-exporting-the-result).

I've tried various approaches but nothing seems to work. For instance, I attempted to utilize openbim-backend-components, specifically the convertIfcBufferToFragments function, but it doesn't work. There seems to be an error within the function itself. I also tried recompiling it into CommonJS, but then its dependent libraries also fail to work.

Please help.